# Exchanging data between MVC- and Windows Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, isolatedstorage, isolatedstoragefile

I have a solution that has a MVC-project and a windows console application. Both projects share the same Backend-Project, that loads and saves data.

I need to exchange the data from these two projects. Therefore I decided to use Isolated scope:

```
    private string LoadInstallationFile()
{
  IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetMachineStoreForDomain();
  if (!isoStore.FileExists(ClientSettingsFile)) return null;
  /* do stuff */
}


private void SaveInstallationFile() {
  IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetMachineStoreForDomain(); 
  using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(ClientSettingsFile, FileMode.CreateNew, isoStore))
  {
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(isoStream))
    {
      writer.WriteLine(data);
    }
  }
}
```

Now Inside the mvc-project I save the Data using "SaveInstallationFile()". I can access that file from within that mvc-project.

But when I try to access the data using the other (console-)project, the File does not exist.

How can I exchange data between these two?
(There is a big chance that both run under different user credentials, so GetUserStore...() IMHO would not work.

**Both, the MVC-Application AND the Console-Application run on the Same Server.**

Comment: The files saved from your MVC app are stored on the server. Your windows app is running on your local machine. Your best bet would be to store your information in a database accessible from both locations.

Comment: @krillgar I clearified that. They both run on the same server. The windows application is a timer-job that does maintenance tasks on the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to use isolated storage API you can use `GetMachineStoreForAssembly` (if this code is shared in the same assembly for both projects). Currently you use different storages for different applications. But to be honest, I would prefer to use database or custom configurable shared disk path as it looks more flexible solution.

`GetMachineStoreForAssembly` is less restrictive version of `GetMachineStoreForDomain` (both of them require code to be in the same assembly but `GetMachineStoreForDomain` requires it to be also in the same application). You can check MSDN documentation:

- First method (`GetMachineStoreForAssembly`) is equivalent of `GetStore(IsolatedStorageScope.Assembly |
  IsolatedStorageScope.Machine, null, null)`
- Second method is equivalent of `GetStore(IsolatedStorageScope.Assembly |
  IsolatedStorageScope.Domain | IsolatedStorageScope.Machine,
  null, null);` (so, it includes one additional flag that's why it's more restrictive)

And also both of them check calling assembly. Not root executing assembly.

Comment: I have no access to that machine. I thought, the parent Assembly would be used, not the backend-assembly for GetMachineStoreForAssembly()

Comment: Edited answer to clarify it (GetMachineStoreForDomain is more restrictive than GetMachineStoreForAssembly)